# Pythonic way to retrieve case sensitive path?

Tags: python, linux, windows, path, directory

I was wondering if there was a faster way to implement a function that returns a case-sensitive path in python. One of the solutions I came up with works with both linux and windows, but requires that I iterate os.listdir, which can be slow.

This solution works fine for an application and context that does not need plenty of speed:

```
def correctPath(start, path):
    'Returns a unix-type case-sensitive path, works in windows and linux'
    start = unicode(start);
    path = unicode(path);
    b = '';
    if path[-1] == '/':
        path = path[:-1];
    parts = path.split('\\');
    d = start;
    c = 0;
    for p in parts:
        listing = os.listdir(d);
        _ = None;
        for l in listing:
            if p.lower() == l.lower():
                if p != l:
                    c += 1;
                d = os.path.join(d, l);
                _ = os.path.join(b, l);
                break;
        if not _:
            return None;
        b = _;

    return b, c; #(corrected path, number of corrections)

>>> correctPath('C:\\Windows', 'SYSTEM32\\CmD.EXe')
(u'System32\\cmd.exe', 2)
```

This however, will not be as fast when the context is gathering filenames from a large 50,000+ entry database.

One method would be to create a dict tree for each directory. Match the dict tree with the directory parts of the path, and if a key-miss occurs, perform an os.listdir to find and create a dict entry for the new directory and remove the unused parts or keep a variable counter as a way to assign a "lifetime" to each directory.

Comment: Just a side note, PEP8 says that you should always have your docstrings enclosed in triple double quotes like so: `"""Returns a unix-type case-sensitive path, works in windows and linux"""`

Comment: Another note, within Python, forward slashes are valid in paths, including Windows. So you could always use `/` internally and render the `\\` only if/as you need it outside of Python.

Comment: Sorry, another note. What's the deal with all the semicolons? You don't really need them unless you are putting multiple program lines on a single text line, and even then, it's considered bad practice.

Comment: The database I'm using uses windows paths, so I don't think I have to worry that much. I'm converting a metadata database from Winamp to Rhythmbox. Also thanks for the docstring tip, no one tells me these things. Also about the semicolon thing, I cannot help it. If I were to release my program I promise I'll remove them.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project

Comment: A couple of comments: Use os.path.sep instead of hard-coding the path separator '\' or '//'.  So `parts = path.split(os.path.sep)` is a bit cleaner.  You can also use splitdrive() to handle the drive in a portable way.  Otherwise the approach looks about right, unless you expect to revisit the same directory structure repeatedly, in which case you'd want to add a cache that maps lower-case path names to corrected path names, so you don't have to do all the IO.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's all context specific really. The path split is necessary for me because the database I'm reading from uses Windows path. The use on `start` is useful in that the database I'm converting to requires a mount path, so it's not a drive letter but rather the whole thing is a windows to linux path conversion.

Comment: @DeepYellow, The cache idea was my suggestion at the bottom, I decided to go for the sub-directory approach because I have more than 2 folder deeps in subdirectories to deal with. A simple file path without the filename in lower case as a cache works well too. My project is somewhat already complete, I'd just like to get the script going a bit faster. Without path correcting, I get 500~600 files/sec, with path correcting I get down to 100 files/sec.

Comment: @chaz: Sorry I couldn't be more help then, happy coding!

Comment: That's quite alright, thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

The following is a slight re-write of your own code with three modifications: checking if the filename is already correct before matching, processing the listing to lowercase before testing, using index to find the relevant 'true case' file.

```
def corrected_path(start, path):
    '''Returns a unix-type case-sensitive path, works in windows and linux'''
    start = unicode(start)
    path = unicode(path)
    corrected_path = ''
    if path[-1] == '/':
        path = path[:-1]
    parts = path.split('\\')
    cd = start
    corrections_count = 0

    for p in parts:
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(cd,p)): # Check it's not correct already
            listing = os.listdir(cd)

            cip = p.lower()
            cilisting = [l.lower() for l in listing]

            if cip in cilisting:
                l = listing[ cilisting.index(cip) ] # Get our real folder name
                cd = os.path.join(cd, l)
                corrected_path = os.path.join(corrected_path, l)
                corrections_count += 1
            else:
                return False # Error, this path element isn't found
        else:
            cd = os.path.join(cd, p)
            corrected_path = os.path.join(corrected_path, p)

    return corrected_path, corrections_count
```

I'm not sure if this will be much faster, though there is a little less testing going on, plus the 'already-correct' catch at the beginning may help.

Comment: Not sure lowering them all first in one go is faster than lowering them all in one each check, but it sure does look nicer though.

Comment: Yup, though I would think it would be reasonably fast even for a massive list. If you're processing >1 path, the biggest speed-up would be by caching the corrections at each level. I'd push out each step of the tree (corrected_path, and an equivalent uncorrected_path build from p) and perform a lookup using that before starting the walk. I can write up an example if you like?

Comment: You mean storing previous corrected paths in a cache to minimize os.listdir calls? If so, then I already have that implementation lying somewhere, wouldn't hurt to post another one.

Answer (score 0):

An extended version with case-insensitive caching to pull out the corrected path:

```
import os,re

def corrected_paths(start, pathlist):
    ''' This wrapper function takes a list of paths to correct vs. to allow caching '''

    start = unicode(start)
    pathlist = [unicode(path[:-1]) if path[-1] == '/' else unicode(path) for path in pathlist ]

    # Use a dict as a cache, storing oldpath > newpath for first-pass replacement
    # with path keys from incorrect to corrected paths
    cache = dict() 
    corrected_path_list = []
    corrections_count = 0
    path_split = re.compile('(/+|\+)')

    for path in pathlist:
        cd = start
        corrected_path = ''
        parts = path_split.split(path)

        # Pre-process against the cache
        for n,p in enumerate(parts):
            # We pass *parts to send through the contents of the list as a series of strings
            uncorrected_path= os.path.join( cd, *parts[0:len(parts)-n] ).lower() # Walk backwards
            if uncorrected_path in cache:
                # Move up the basepath to the latest matched position
                cd = os.path.join(cd, cache[uncorrected_path])
                parts = parts[len(parts)-n:] # Retrieve the unmatched segment
                break; # First hit, we exit since we're going backwards

        # Fallback to walking, from the base path cd point
        for n,p in enumerate(parts):

            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(cd,p)): # Check it's not correct already
            #if p not in os.listdir(cd): # Alternative: The above does not work on Mac Os, returns case-insensitive path test

                listing = os.listdir(cd)

                cip = p.lower()
                cilisting = [l.lower() for l in listing]

                if cip in cilisting:

                    l = listing[ cilisting.index(cip) ] # Get our real folder name
                    # Store the path correction in the cache for next iteration
                    cache[ os.path.join(cd,p).lower() ] = os.path.join(cd, l)
                    cd = os.path.join(cd, l)
                    corrections_count += 1

                else:
                    print "Error %s not in folder %s" % (cip, cilisting)
                    return False # Error, this path element isn't found

            else:
                cd = os.path.join(cd, p)

        corrected_path_list.append(cd)

    return corrected_path_list, corrections_count
```

On an example run for a set of paths, this reduces the number of listdirs considerably (this is obviously dependent on how alike your paths are):

```
corrected_paths('/Users/', ['mxF793/ScRiPtS/meTApaTH','mxF793/ScRiPtS/meTApaTH/metapAth/html','mxF793/ScRiPtS/meTApaTH/metapAth/html/css','mxF793/ScRiPts/PuBfig'])
([u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/metapath', u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/metapath/metapath/html', u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/metapath/metapath/html/css', u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/pubfig'], 14)
([u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/metapath', u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/metapath/metapath/html', u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/metapath/metapath/html/css', u'/Users/mxf793/Scripts/pubfig'], 5)
```

On the way to this I realised the on Mac OSX Python returns path matches as if they are case-insensitive, so the test for existence always succeeds. In that case the listdir can be shifted up to replace it.

Comment: Looks good. I really like the regex object used to detect redundant slashes. I think it should be `r'(/+|\+)'`, using `[]` will inadvertently match `|` characters.